# WooCommerce - formatted billing address

Tags: php, wordpress

I am little depressed for a few days now, trying to find a solution for this, so any help would be much appreciated.

In myfunctions.php in Wordpress, I added the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $address_fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
     unset($address_fields['postcode']);
     $address_fields['company']['required'] = false;

     $address_fields['chamber_of_commerce_no'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Chamber of Commerce No', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('Chamber of Commerce No', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => true,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
     );

     $address_fields['fiscal_code'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Fiscal Code', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('For romanian companies', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => false,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
     );

    $address_fields['vat_code'] = array(
        'label'     => __('VAT Code', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('For foreign companies', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => false,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
     );

     $address_fields['bank_account_no'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Bank Account No', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('Bank Account No', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => true,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
     );

     $address_fields['bank'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Bank', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('Bank', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => true,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
     );


     return $address_fields;
    }
```

After this, I tried adding the fields to get_formatted_billing_address function:

```
 public function get_formatted_billing_address() {
        if ( ! $this->formatted_billing_address ) {

            // Formatted Addresses
            $address = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address', array(
                'company'       => $this->billing_company,
                'address_1'         => $this->billing_address_1,
                'address_2'         => $this->billing_address_2,
                'city'          => $this->billing_city,
                'country'       => $this->billing_country,
                'bank_account_no'   => $this->billing_bank_account_no,
                'bank'          => $this->billing_bank,
                'chamber_of_commerce_no'=> $this->billing_chamber_of_commerce_no,
                'fiscal_code'       => $this->billing_fiscal_code,
                'vat_code'      => $this->billing_vat_code

            ), $this );

            $this->formatted_billing_address = WC()->countries->get_formatted_address( $address );
        }
        return $this->formatted_billing_address;
    }
```

It did not work.
Then I tried adding a filter:

```
    add_filter ('woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address', 'custom_override_formatted_billing_address');



function custom_override_formatted_billing_address () {

        $address = array(

        'company'       => $this->billing_company,

        'address_1'         => $this->billing_address_1,

        'address_2'         => $this->billing_address_2,

        'city'          => $this->billing_city,

        'state'         => $this->billing_state,

        'country'       => $this->billing_country,

        'bank_account_no'   => $this->billing_bank_account_no,

        'bank'          => $this->billing_bank,

        'chamber_of_commerce_no'=> $this->billing_chamber_of_commerce_no,

        'fiscal_code'       => $this->billing_fiscal_code,

        'vat_code'      => $this->billing_vat_code

);



    return $address;

   }
```

Still, it did not work.

How can do I make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you actually tell us what you are trying to do..

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_localisation_address_formats', 'your_func')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".